# Iterate through Page Alias in Kentico 8.1

Tags: kentico

Is there a way to iterate in code C# all the page alias (URLs) of each Kentico Page in the website ?

I am using Kentico 8.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `DocumentAliasInfoProvider` to do that.

```cs
// Specify site identifier
var siteId = 3;
// Get all docs
var docs = DocumentHelper.GetDocuments().Where("NodeSiteID", QueryOperator.Equals, siteId).Columns("NodeID");
foreach (var doc in docs)
{
    // Iterate through docs and retrieve aliases for each of them
    var aliases = DocumentAliasInfoProvider.GetDocumentAliases().Where("AliasNodeID", QueryOperator.Equals, doc.NodeID);
    foreach (var alias in aliases)
    {
        lbl.Text += alias.AliasURLPath + "<br />";
    }
}
```

If you don't want to iterate through documents you can directly select aliases of a site:

```cs
var aliases2 = DocumentAliasInfoProvider.GetDocumentAliases().Where("AliasSiteID", QueryOperator.Equals, siteId);
foreach (var alias in aliases2)
{
    lbl.Text += alias.AliasURLPath + "<br />";
}
```

The site identifier can be retrieved by calling:

```cs
// For sites other than current
var siteId = SiteInfoProvider.GetSiteID("codename_of_your_site");
// OR
var siteId = SiteContext.CurrentSiteID;
```

Please refer to the [API Examples](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/API+examples). [image]

Comment: How do I get the siteId for my site ?